# missing images on heroku deployment process

Tags: heroku, webpack, buildpack

I tried to deploy a react app with webpack 
I used create-react-app- buildpack https://github.com/mars/create-react-app-buildpack

I have static.json

```
{
  "root": "public/",
  "routes":{
    "/**": "index.html"
  }
}
```

I set NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=true NODE_ENV=production YARN_PRODUCTION=true
 but I get this error 
seems it can not access to those images

```
ERROR in ./src/Shared/Header/Header.jsx
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../../assets/images/logos/logo-white.png' in '/tmp/build_abbb8ced25af1dcc8cb901be4bc3d3e9/src/Shared/Header'
 @ ./src/Shared/Header/Header.jsx 2:0-60
 @ ./src/HomePage/HomePage.jsx
 @ ./src/HomePage/index.js
 @ ./src/App/App.jsx
 @ ./src/App/index.js
 @ ./src/index.jsx
 @ multi core-js/fn/promise core-js/es6/object core-js/es6/array ./src/index.jsx
ERROR in ./src/LoginPage/LoginPage.jsx
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../assets/images/logos/logo-orange.png' in '/tmp/build_abbb8ced25af1dcc8cb901be4bc3d3e9/src/LoginPage'
 @ ./src/LoginPage/LoginPage.jsx 10:0-58
 @ ./src/LoginPage/index.js
 @ ./src/App/App.jsx
 @ ./src/App/index.js
 @ ./src/index.jsx
 @ multi core-js/fn/promise core-js/es6/object core-js/es6/array ./src/index.jsx
ERROR in ./src/SignUpPage/SignUpPage.jsx
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../assets/images/logos/logo-orange.png' in '/tmp/build_abbb8ced25af1dcc8cb901be4bc3d3e9/src/SignUpPage'
 @ ./src/SignUpPage/SignUpPage.jsx 7:0-58
 @ ./src/SignUpPage/index.js
 @ ./src/App/App.jsx
 @ ./src/App/index.js
 @ ./src/index.jsx
 @ multi core-js/fn/promise core-js/es6/object core-js/es6/array ./src/index.jsx
Child html-webpack-plugin for "index.html":
```

any Idea how can I fix it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I founded the problem It was related to case sensitive and fix by make correction on referencing address

Answer (score 0):

In my case I resized an image online, and in the logs it showed .JPG but in my git and explorer was .jpg so I had to rename it to .png to be able to push